# Videowhisper - video not push to media server

Tags: red5, flash-media-server, video-recording

I have installed Red5 on the media server and configured VideoWhisper RTMP Application there, which is accessed from the hosting demo. The application demo show/enable webcam, but when I click on record the application only take a snapshot but didn't push the video to media server.

Anybody experience this before?... here is my screenshot of the RTMP url on videowhisper test tool:
[image]

Comment: I've seen errors with videowhisper before, but the first thing you need to do is make sure the videowhisper app exists and is running on the server. Look at your webapps directory to see if videowhisper subdirectory exists.

Comment: Yes videowhisper app exist on media server with the same name.. i have follow the steps from here.. http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=RTMP+Applications

Comment: There is a "NetConnection.Call.Failed", you'll need to turn up the logging and get details on that to proceed. Also which version of Red5 are you using?